# Facebook Login, username issues

Tags: facebook, authentication

I've got a problem is my coding. Basically, I'm trying to call the name up of a user when they're logged in. So, they 'Allow' the program, and when logged in, it says "Hello Tom", or whatever their name is.

Here's the code:

```
<?php if ($user): ?>
<?
$faceuser = "http://graph.facebook.com/" . $user;
$pageContent = file_get_contents('$faceuser');
$facebookname  = json_decode($pageContent);
echo $facebookname->name;
?>
Hello <fb:name uid='' useyou='false' possessive='true' />!
<?php else: ?>
<a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>"><img src="../../images/login.gif" width="75" height="27" alt="Login"></a>
<?php endif ?>
```

As you can see the code is becoming messy, but also it just will not compile however I phrase it. Can anyone help please?

Many Thanks,

Tom Cusack

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the PHP-SDK and the Example you get with it.
https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk
https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php

With the PHP-SDK it easy to create a solution for your problem.

But you dont need the users to login to your app if you use  you only need to initialize the JS-SDK with xfbml:true.